Usage of なのは in this sentence?
肉体的損傷から限界なのは把握している
Why is なの used here? I understand it's akin to "From your physical damage, I understand you have reached the limit" but why なの is used?

This 限界 is used as a no-adjective, and なの is how you nominalize a na-/no-adjective and a copula.

(verb) 彼が歌うのを把握しています。
I understand that he will sing.
(i-adjective) 彼女が美しいのを把握しています。
I understand that she is beautiful.
(na-adjective) 問題が簡単なのを把握しています。
I understand that the question is easy.
(no-adjective) あなたが限界なのを把握しています。
I understand that you are at your limit.
(noun) これがスマホなのを把握しています。
I understand that this is a smartphone.

の is a noun, and the word before it is in the attributive form (連体形).
